# Failure when receiving data from the peer in GitHub's webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, webhooks

i'm trying to create a webhook between local installed Jenkins on my laptop and GitHub, which will trigger every time i push to repository . i've created a Jenkin's job and a webhook with payload field : "http://MyIPHere:8080/github-webhooks/" but everytime i get message "We couldn’t deliver this payload: Failure when receiving data from the peer" . What can be wrong?

Comment: Either your IP or the port is not publicly accessible. You might want to check this out https://superuser.com/questions/526899/how-to-make-my-ip-publicly-accessible-to-make-my-local-tomcat-server-public

Comment: that's actually a very helpfull, thank you!

Comment: Seems as though this is very similar to my own question. In the end I downloaded ngrok, checked the address mapping in the terminal that appears, for the port that jenkins was running on, and replaced the address in the github webhooks section with this address and appended /github-webhooks ont the end of it and that resolved the issue.